# Can you please explain whether this game is a game with multiple events?

Tags: dice

There's a game where there are two dices distributed to each player. The player that rolls a higher number than the other wins the game. My teacher tells me that this game is not a game with multiple events. Can you please explain if this is true or not? Thank you.

Comment: What is a "game with multiple events?". Certainly there are two rolls of the dice.  You can combine them into one roll of all four dice, as long as you keep track of which dice belong to each player, which might be one event.

Comment: My teacher was referring to a game with like a coin and a die, but I wasn't sure if he was right.

Comment: That term does not have an accepted definition that I know of, so there should be one in your class.  Please quote it exactly.  Once you do, we can try to apply it.

Comment: @WoojinRho Strictly speaking, we can also combine a coin and a die. So, it would be inconsequent to consider this as "multiple events" , but not "two dices". The teacher should clarify exactly what he/she means with "multiple events", since there is no "official" definition.

Comment: My teacher just emailed me back and stated 'occurrences that are preferably unrelated and definitely independent of each other - examples in classes prior were: A bag with colored beads, followed by tossing of a fair coin/die; OR a fair coin, followed by throwing of a fair six-sided die; OR spinning 5 sided spinner and then picking a ball from a bag containing many different colors. Any of these constitutes as an event, and this any two or more of them would then constitute multiple events. Repeating one, or using the same one twice (or more) is still a single event, albeit with repetition.'